# How can I make picture 2 to be of same width as picture 1 while keeping its proportions in Picture Collage Maker Pro?

Tags: resize, picture-collage-maker-pro

I use [Picture Collage Maker Pro](https://www.pearlmountainsoft.com/picture-collage-maker) on Windows 10. I have 2 pictures in my collage. How can make picture 2 to be of same width as picture 1 while keeping picture 2's proportions (i.e., proportionally resize picture 2)?

I tried selecting picture 1 and picture 2, then right click, `Make Same Size` -> `Width`, but that doesn't keep its proportions:

[image]

[image]

The picture's property box allows users to specify a width but it doesn't change the height proportionally:

[image]

Comment: I do not know specifically  about the program you are using. In most programs you would click and drag on one of the corner handles to resize  while holding the shift key to maintain original proportions. I did look through the info for picture maker collage pro and there was not a lot of documentation/ usage instructions that I could find. Possibly easier to do the sizing in another more robust photo editor (Photoshop or Gimp) before you bring them into the program you are using.

Comment: @Kyle thanks,  click and drag on one of the corner handles to resize  works pretty well but the issue is I'm trying to match a target width.

Comment: So, you can resize in the Object Properties dialog box but it does not allow for constraining the proportions. You can do the math yourself and get the relative width to height proportion and then use that proportion to adjust the height to be the same proportion to your target width.

Comment: Or move one under the other and do it by eye...

Comment: @Kyle thanks, yes, looks like we have do the math ourselves :/

Answer (score 0):

The image with the blue background looks like it has been cropped, not resized.  But you appear to be trying to squish the image with the red background by resizing it.

I am not familiar with this software at all, but I can clearly see there is a crop tool in your screenshot.

Try using the crop tool instead.

[image]